# Flux does not wait for completion of elements before 'then'

Tags: java, spring-boot, netty, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I am failing to understand the issue and I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

I want to wait for Flux to end and then return `Mono` of `serverResponse`

I have attached the code snippet, the `doOnNext` will populate the `categoryIdToPrintRepository`.

I have looked around on how to return mono after flux ends and found the 'then' but still the 'then' method is being executed way before the onNextSite is being processed, this results with the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'producer' type is unknown to ReactiveAdapterRegistry
```

What am I doing wrong?

```
 public Mono<ServerResponse> retrieveCatalog(ServerRequest ignored) {
        return Mono.just("start").flatMap(id ->
                Flux.fromIterable(appSettings.getSites())
                        .subscribeOn(ForkJoinPoolScheduler.create("SiteCatalogScheduler"))
                        .doOnNext(this::onNextSite)
                        .then(Mono.from(ServerResponse.ok().body(categoryIdToPrintRepository.getSortedTreeValues(), String.class))));

    }

    private void onNextSite(Integer siteId) {
        IntStream.range(1, appSettings.getCatalogMaxValue()).parallel().forEach(catalogId -> {
            Optional<SiteCatalogCategoryDTO> cacheData =
                    siteCatalogCacheUseCaseService.getSiteCatalogResponseFromCache(siteId, catalogId);
            cacheData.ifPresentOrElse(siteCatalogCategoryDTO -> {/*do nothing already exist in cache*/},
                    () -> {
                    Mono<SiteCatalogCategoryDTO> catalogCategoryDTOMono = WebClient.create(getUri(siteId, catalogId))
                            .get().retrieve().bodyToMono(SiteCatalogCategoryDTO.class);
                    catalogCategoryDTOMono.subscribe(siteCatalogCategoryDTO ->
                            handleSiteServerResponse(siteCatalogCategoryDTO, siteId, catalogId));
            });
        });
    }


    private void handleSiteServerResponse(SiteCatalogCategoryDTO siteCatalogCategoryDTO,
                                          int siteId, int catalogId) {
        if (siteCatalogCategoryDTO.getResponseStatus().equals(ResponseStatus.SUCCESS))
            Flux.fromIterable(siteCatalogCategoryDTO.getMappingList())
                    .subscribe(mapSCC -> {
                        categoryIdToPrintRepository.insertIntoTree(mapSCC.getCategoryId(),
                                "Site " + siteId + " - Catalog " + catalogId + " is mapped to category " + "\"" +
                                        mapSCC.getCategoryName() + "\" (" + mapSCC.getCategoryId() + ")");
                        siteCatalogCacheUseCaseService.insertIntoSiteCatalogCache(siteId, catalogId, siteCatalogCategoryDTO);
                    });
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing several things wrong you should not `subscribe` in your application, and you are having void methods, which should not be used in reactive programming unless in specific places.

here is some example code:

```
// Nothing will happen, we are not returning anything, we can't subscribe
private void doSomething() {
    Mono.just("Foo");
}

// complier error
doSomething().subscribe( ... );
```

Your application is a `publisher` the calling client, is the subscriber, thats why we return a Mono or a Flux out to the calling client, they `subscribe`.

You have solved it this way:

```
private void doSomething() {
    Mono.just("Foo").subscribe( ... );
}

doSomething();
```

Now you are subscribing to yourself to get things running, this is not the correct way, as mentioned before, the calling client is the subscriber, not you.

Correct way:

```
private Mono<String> doSomething() {
    return Mono.just("Foo");
}

// This is returned out to the calling client, they subscribe
return doSomething();
```

As a Mono/Flux completes, it will emit a signal, this signal will trigger the next and the next and the next in the chain.

So my opinion of what you need to do is the following:

- Remove **all** `subscribes`, if you want to do things there are functions like, `flatmap`, `map`, `doOnSuccess` etc. keep the chain instact all the way out to the client.
- Remove all **void** functions, make sure they return a `Flux` or a `Mono` and if you want to **not** return something return a `Mono<Void>` by using the `Mono.empty()` function so that the chain will be complete.

As soon as you use a Mono/Flux you need to handle the return so that others can chain on.

Update:

In order for `then` to trigger, you must return something, it will return when the previous mono/flux completes.

example:

```
private Flux<String> doSomething() {
    return Flux.just("Foo", "Bar", "FooBar")
               .doOnNext(string -> {
                   return // return something
               });
}

// Ignore what was return from doSomething and return something else when the flux has completed (so only trigger on the completed signal from the flux)
return doSomething().then( ... );
```

Comment: I understand your remakrs, but the problem still remains, I don't want to return the flux, I want to finish the flux execution and then return a mono as the response to the client, How can this be done in spring webflux?

Comment: read the documentation for `then(Mono<V> other)` it states `Let this Flux complete then play signals from a provided Mono` which means if you return a `Flux` when that flux completes (whatever you want it to do) it will then return what you have put in your `then`.

Comment: `you should not subscribe in your application`, why not? Also void methods are fine for `doOnNext` which should be used only for side effects. The issue is they are expecting the side effects to affect the original Mono chain. Also AFAIK no method signature for `doOnNext` allows you to return anything, since it only takes a consumer.

Comment: Because the calling client looses the ability to control backpressure. And i did never claim that doOnNext did not take a void method, so please read before you comment.

Comment: You don't control back pressure in `doOnNext`, so not sure your point there. Also you say `You are doing several things wrong ...  you are having void methods`, but OP is using them in doOnNext, so again how is that wrong? What did I read incorrectly?